# JQuery output: nodeName uppercase to lowercase

Tags: jquery

I have create a HTML cleaner that strips special characters, empty tags, classes, ids, and attributes. All you do is paste the html code into the converter and it out puts the clean code.

Please look at the source code here:

//jsfiddle.net/bd7cj04v/3/

Problem:

When the tag names are outputted they are in caps. I understand that it is native for nodeNames to output in capitalization. How can I ensure (in my code) that the output is lowercase. Help on this will be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, replace

```
value.nodeName
```

with

```
value.nodeName.toLowerCase()
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your function, you can call `.toLowerCase()` on your string, like

```
var myName = "NAME";
alert(myName.toLowerCase());
```

This should make sure your tag name is always in lowercase.

Comment: If he does that on whole result var that he has built he will convert everything to lowercase, including any content inside the tags. It should be done just on the nodeName variable.

Answer (score 0):

There's a function called `toLowerCase()`.

If you use it on your node you have what you want.